# <Object> has no method 'addMatchers' - jasmine 1.3.1 compatibility with jasmine jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am using jquery 1.7.1 and jasmine 1.3.1, I added jasmine 2.0.3 from https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery when I ran this test

```
        it("Should invoke the OnTheMove_QueryDatabaseExecuted event.", function () {
        var spy = spyOnEvent(document, 'OnTheMove_QueryDatabaseExecuted');
        $(document).trigger('OnTheMove_QueryDatabaseExecuted');
        expect('OnTheMove_QueryDatabaseExecuted').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(document);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });
```

I got 34 instances of error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addMatchers'
```

I have done some readaround and now I am assuming this is compatibility issue.
**Question:** What is the highest version of jasmine-jquery that is compatible with jasmine 1.3.1?
Are both of these versions compatible with jquery 1.7.1 and what is the highest jquery version that is compatable?

Answer (score 0):

I had to update karma-jasmine to fix this problem, but I had to modify the package.json entry manually.

The line should read:

```
"karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0"
```

I have had no negative repercussions from the upgrade, and jQuery shouldn't be affected.